# Heterogeneous and homogeneous collection of objects in C#

Tags: c#, collections

With a little bit of definition, can someone please give us code-examples of the both collection types for understanding purposes.

Comment: This should be a Documentation Request. That said, the answer shouldn't be that broad here.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @TravisJ indeed post is not too broad, it is simple request for examples showing negative amount of research. Possibly will get downvotes due to lack of research and potentially get closed as "request for examples".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you give us a code-example for a `homogeneous collection of objects`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In heterogeneous collection, you can add any type of data into collection for example,

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.Add(1); // integer 
a.Add("any string"); // any string 
a.Add(new { any = "Test Data" }); //any object
```

- For a heterogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<Object>` (in C#) or `List(Of Object)` (in Visual Basic) type.
- For a homogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<T>` class.

  e.g. 
    `List<int> lst = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 };`

  above, you can't have multiple data-types in same collection i.e. { 1,2,3,"a" }

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx for more

Comment: Please give a code-example of `homogeneous collection of objects`?

Comment: @RehanKhan please check edit